# MSMQ 'stale handles'

Tags: msmq

I'm writing a custom wrapper for native MSMQ in C#/ Having looked at the System.Messaging code in ILSpy, I notice that this implementation does quite a lot to work around 'stale' queue handles. I don't handle this situation at present, and am wondering in what circumstances a handle can become 'stale'?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have any clue to what makes these 'stale' handles occuring, but they do that quite often. So you should also handle the stale handles in your wrapper. I had to implement it in MSMQ Studio as it would have been impossible to use the native api's otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

A stale handle no longer points to a queue. For example, if the destination queue manager restarts, the queue handle will no longer be known to it and communication using that handle should fail.